# invalidate previous tokens and check a user has JWT token or not

Tags: laravel, api, authentication, jwt

I have an API with Laravel 8 and use JWT for authentication

When I log in several times, a new token is created for the user, but the problem is that the previously created tokens are valid and usable. (Until the token expires)

So how can I fix this bug?

this is my `login()` and `createNewToken()` method in  **`AuthController()`** :

```
    public function login(Request $request) {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json($validator->errors(), 422);
        }

        if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($validator->validated())) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'احراز نشده'], 401);
        }

        return $this->createNewToken($token);
    }


    protected function createNewToken($token) {
        return response()->json([
            'access_token' => $token,
            'token_type' => 'bearer',
            'expires_in' => JWTAuth::factory()->getTTL() * 240,
            
            'user' => auth()->user()
        ]);
    }
```

I think the best way is to check in login method , if this user has a token, invalidate it and create a new one, else create a new token.

but I don't know how to check the user token with JWT

In advance thanks for your help.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's how JWTs work. If you want invalidation, you need a blacklist, and that's basically re-introducing the issues with sessions JWT was designed to avoid... and at that point, you're probably better off with sessions in Redis or something. http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2016/06/13/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check for sessions in the login method.

For example, you can create unique IDs for sessions and set them as *jti* claims for each token you issue (see [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7519#page-10)). You need to store them somewhere (e.g. a cache data store). Then, during login, you check if the *jti* of the received JWT is valid. This way, you can check if a token is revoked or not.

But keep in mind that this undermines the stateless nature of the JTI.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach when using JWTs is to have short lived access tokens (e.g. 5-15 minutes) and use refresh tokens to get new tokens, so that the user doesn't have to log in every 5 minutes. In such a scenario you should not be bothered by an old token - it will only be valid for a few minutes anyway.

If you really need an option to "revoke" access tokens, you should implement it in the part which validates received JWTs, not the login method. As @Deniz suggested in his answer you will need a store to keep some data which can be validated with the content of the JWT. Using session ID in the `jti` claim is one valid option. Another option would be to keep in a database a timestamp of the last issued access token for a given user, and then validate the `iat` claim - issued at. If you receive a token for a given user with `iat` lower than what you have in the DB, you reject the request.

Anyway, if you want to revoke a JWT only because someone logged in again, then it sounds like you want to use sessions, and JWTs are not good for sessions. Just go with plain old cookies.

Comment: access tokens are short-lived, and it can be ignored. But refresh token is long-lived and it can still be used for a long time. and it's bad for paid applications.